# Proof involving symmetric bilinear forms and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form, change-of-basis

Let $f$ $:$ $V$$\times$$V$ $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb R$ be a symmetric bilinear form.

Let $A, B$ be the matrices of $f$ with respect to possibly different bases.

I want to prove that there exists $P$ such that $B$ $=$ $P^T$$AP$.

Please can anyone lend a hand here?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A$ and $A'$ are the matrices of the form with respect to the bases $B$ and $B'$, respectively. Since $B$ and $B'$ are bases for $V$, there exists and invertible square matrix $P$ such that $B'=BP$. We'll show that this means $A'=P^tAP$.

Let $X,X'$ be the coordinate vectors of $v\in V$ with respect to the bases $A,A'$, respectively. Then $v=BX=B'X'$ and with analogous notation $w=BY=B'Y'$ if $w\in V$. Then $$\langle v,w \rangle =X^tAY=(PX')^tA(PY')=X'^t(P^tAP)Y'$$ which identifies $P^tAP$ as the matrix of the form with respect to the basis $B'$.

Note that the symmetry condition of the form was not used in the proof. This is because the result holds for any bilinear form on a real vector space.

Comment: Aren't the coordinate vectors of $v$ w.r.t bases $B$ and $B'$? - 4th line of the proof

Comment: A set of vectors $B=(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ is a basis for the vector space $V$ if and only if every vector $v\in V$ can be written as a unique linear combination $v=b_1x_1+b_2x_2+...+ b_nx_n=BX$. In this case, $X$ is called the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to the basis $B$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @rpf why is $$\langle v,w \rangle =X^tAY'$$ and not $$\langle v,w \rangle =(BX)^tA(BY')$$?

Comment: This is because the matrix of a form $\langle\;, \rangle$ with respect to a basis $B=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ is defined as $A=(a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij}=\langle b_i,b_j\rangle$. Thus if $X, Y$ are the coordinate vectors of $v,w$ in the basis $B$, then $$\langle v,w \rangle = \langle \sum_i b_ix_i,\sum_jb_jy_j\rangle =\sum_{i,j}x_i\langle b_i,b_j\rangle y_j=\sum_{i,j}x_ia_{ij}y_j=X^tAY.$$